# How to create a local pypi mirror?

Tags: python, pypi, mirror

I want to create a local pypi mirror according to the web tutorial.
[set local pypi mirror](https://aboutsimon.com/blog/2012/02/24/Create-a-local-PyPI-mirror.html)

Here is my way.

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python2.7   get-pip.py
sudo pip2.7 install  pep381client
mkdir  mirror
pep381run  /tmp/mirror
```

An error info occurs here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pep381run", line 23, in <module>
    state = pep381client.Synchronization.initialize(targetdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pep381client/__init__.py", line 96, in initialize
    status.projects_to_do = set(xmlrpc().list_packages())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1243, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1602, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1283, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1331, in single_request
    response.msg,
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for pypi.python.org/pypi: 403 Must access using HTTPS instead of HTTP>
```

How to create a local pypi mirror ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pep381client` seems to be quite outdated (last updated in 2011). You need something more fresh like `devpi` or `pypi-server`.